# Passing Global Variable to client side HTML in Google Web Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a global variable `curT` in my google script codes. I want to use them inside the client side java script codes. I can see them inside the html as I injected them before evaluate. But I can't access them inside page scripts. I tried `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler` and added a function to read and returns that global variable. But again I can't see it! I also added a JS variable in my HTML to save returned result of `onSuccessHandler` ... no luck again!

```html
      <script>
      var TEAM="";
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(cTeam).currentTeam();
      function cTeam(res){
        alert ('Returned team Name'= res);
        TEAM = res;
      }       
      </script>
```

my server side code in an google script file:

```
    function currentTeam(){
      Logger.log('Team Name is Requested');
      if (curT.length===0){
        return 'ALL';
      } else{
        return curT;
      }
    }
```

1) is this only way for passing global JS variables to the client side codes?  I mean we should have function!
2) what is wrong in my code or approach?

Thanks a lot,
M

Comment: i found this working though for my purpose. I think the JS variables are not active in HTML!
So I used the passed parameter instead. 
`      <script>
      var TEAM="";
      google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {        TEAM=location.parameters["t"][0];});  
      </script>
`

Comment: Do you want to set the variable value in the html when the html first loads?  You can use a scriptlet for that, which is called "Templated html"  Search the documentation for "templated html" I wouldn't use an `alert()` for debugging.  Use `console.log('var name: ' + variableName)`  Then view the browser developer tools log.  Open the developer tools with f12.

Comment: no As I explained using scriptlet, I added those variable to the html. (I used "I injected them" wording for that) My issue was with calling and using those variable in javascript section of page. Which I finally used location/ url parameters for that!. Is this good idea?

Comment: The `location.parameters` field is used for getting the URL request parameters.  Which means that a search string needs to be appended to the end of the URL.  example: `http://www.example.com?n=1&name=alice&n=2#headingAnchor`  Are you calling the script with search string parameters on the end?

Comment: After I was not able to get it directly, I passed it to the URL